# git difftol --dir-diff beteen head and files in staging area

Tags: git, diff, kdiff3

I have the following in my ~/.gitconfig

```
    dt = difftool --dir-diff
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
```

So if I want to see what have changed since for example previous commit and the last one I run:

`git dt HEAD HEAD~1 (or git dit HEAD~1 HEAD, doesn't matter.`

Is it possible to do the same for staged but not yet committed files? What I want to do is:

```git dt HEAD <staged_but_not_committed`>``

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with the `--cached` option

```
git difftool -d --cached
git diff --cached
```